# How can I add an expression or objective to an existing pyomo model?

Tags: pyomo

I have defined a model that we can call using make_base_model(demands, earliest_arrivals, travel_times). The model has one expression (which I can use as the objective) and several constraints. Now I want to define a different expression total_fuel_usage(m) and use this as the objective for the same model.

Here's my code, trying to first solve the model using its included expression as the objective and then solving the model using the new expression as the objective.

```
instance = generate_instance(n_nodes=10, seed=0)
travel_times = create_travel_times_matrix(instance)

display(Markdown("## Example instance"))
model = make_base_model(instance["demand"], instance["earliest_arrival"], travel_times)
# Set model objective here, using an earlier defined expression
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=model.total_travel_time)
solve_model(solver, model)
print("Total travel time: %.2f" % model.total_travel_time())

plot_solution(instance["coord"], model)
model.obj.deactivate()

#Set model objective using new expression
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=total_fuel_usage(model), sense=pyo.minimize)
solve_model(solver, model)
```

I get an error for the last line (DegreeError: Highs interface does not support expressions of degree None). Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your expression for the 2nd objective looks suspicious.  Is this a function call or expression or ???:  `total_fuel_usage(model)`?  Try catching that, printing it out and ensuring it is what you think it is.  If that doesn't work, include the source code for that in your question.